# Problem with hidden files and github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a repository stored locally and on GitHub,

This repository is used to store the contents of my website,

After signing up to a CMS and it creating a hidden file in the GitHub directory I changed my mind and wanted to delete the hidden files.

I had performed

```
git pull origin master
```

In order to sync my local files with the files on GitHub, I then removed the hidden files locally and ran the following hoping it would sync the latest file with my local directory.

```
git add *
git commit -m "Removed CMS hidden files"
git push -u origin master
```

However, when doing this I get the following

```
    On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    deleted:    .forestry/front_matter/templates/catalogue-entry.yml
    deleted:    .forestry/settings.yml

Untracked files:
    .DS_Store

no changes added to commit
```

My desired outcome is to what I have locally synced exactly with my GitHub directory removing the hidden files added by the CMS.

Comment: Try `git add --all` instead of `git add *` to see if it works

Comment: Brilliant that did it, many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+file+already+deleted

Comment: May I put it as an answer?

Comment: Sure thing, reason the other suggested links don't answer my question is because I have already removed them locally just wanted to sync both.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh Would you mind expanding your answer to explain the difference between the two commands please?

Comment: You might want to delete or ignore ds_store files.

Comment: @frakman1 I updated the answer, give it a look to see if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Use `git add [--all|-A]` or `git add [.|-A .]` or `git add -u` or `git add '*'`,   instead of `git add *`. One of them might work *(use `git status` to verify which works)*.

---

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572660/9787887) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26343584/9787887):

> - `git add --all` or `git add -A` **stages all changes** *on the whole working tree*
> - `git add -u` **stages modifications and deletions**, *without new files*
> - In *git version 1.x*, `git add .` **staged new files and modifications**, *without deletions - on the whole working tree*.
> - *From git 2.0*, `git add .` *(or `git add -A .`)* however is to **stage new/modified/deleted files *(all changes)*** *- but only on the current directory (`./` directory)*
> - To get the old behavior of `git add .`, we've to [use `--ignore-removal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26343584/9787887)

About `git add *`, from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366771/9787887):

> - In git, `add *` the `*` is interpreted by the shell, and has nothing to do with Git. **If your shell is Bash, files and directories starting with `.` *(hidden files on Linux)* will not be matched by `*`**, so they will not be passed to `git add`, and will not get added to the index.
> - If `git add *` is being **run in a Windows non-bash interpreter**, the `*` however will be passed literally to `git add`. In this case **files and directories whose names start with `.` will get added**.

So the behavior **differs from Windows and Linux for `git add *`**, and the OP probably used a Linux/ *git with a bash shell* system, that's why he got the message:

```
 Changes not staged for commit:
    deleted:    .forestry/front_matter/templates/catalogue-entry.yml
    deleted:    .forestry/settings.yml
```

after did `git add *`, yet because *(with bash shell)* `add *` didn't match the files start with `.`.

Encourage you guys to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366771/9787887) to get more detail about `git add *`.

**Conclusion:** Depends on cases *(which directory you're on, whether you want to delete or add or modify, etc)* one of my suggestions above might work, but `git add [--all,-A]` happens to be the safest one to *stage all changes include hidden files on the whole working tree - whole repository*.

Comment: `git add -u` is the safest way to add modifications and deletions without new files, it shouldn't be part of the "might" work set of commands.

Comment: I wrote "might" work because I haven't tested it yet, yet I'm not super confidently comfortable with git so I wrote "might". About `git add --all`, the OP used it and it did work for him, so I wrote: "will work". If you see you can improve my answer, please do me the favor of giving me an edit suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Seemingly the `git add .` only stages changes of the files **in the current folder** *(`.` folder)* instead of *new files and modifications* as I said above.